# 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'group'

Tags: xcode, swift

The 'messages' code and 'group' code is exactly the same and can't figure out why I am getting the 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'group' error which won't allow me to build and run my app.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Messages")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

    if results?.count > 0 {

        for x:AnyObject in results! {

            if let message = x.message! {

                self.messages.append(message)

            }

        }

    }

    var request2 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Groups")
    request2.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results2 = context.executeFetchRequest(request2, error: nil)

    if results2?.count > 0 {

        for x:AnyObject in results2! {

            if let group = x.group! {

                self.groups.append(group)

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I have looked elsewhere for this same error and couldn't find anything to solve it. I am new to swift / xcode so please cut me some slack if this is a beginner level question! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're casting the x in your for in loop to a type of AnyObject, if this is the desired behavior that's fine but I think you're probably trying to retrieve the value of a key from a core data object, in which case you may be looking for

```
x.valueForKey("keyName") as? DESIRED_TYPE
```

If you're using different types of objects then you can cast them in your results array where you execute the fetch request

```
var results2 = context.executeFetchRequest(request2, error: nil) as! [YourCustom or NSManagedObjects]
```